# Hide mongodb password using heroku so I can also push to public repo on github

Tags: mongodb, heroku, github

I am trying to be able to push to heroku and a public github repo without having my database password revealed on github, and without having to change the `.gitignore` every time.

In the URI for mongodb on heroku, it suggests doing `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<address>` in your production environment script.

Is there a way to hide this on github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out the answer!

In your production configuration for Heroku, use your Heroku "Config Variables" for your database URI.

For example, if you use MongoHQ, use `process.env.MONGOHQ_URL` for your URI, no password or username needed because it is connecting to the local server.

If you use MongoLabs use `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI`.

Hope this helps someone, I definitely found it useful!

Comment: Years later and it still helps!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `git push heroku main` to push to heroku with your details and make sure your site is working on heroku
2. Then use .env file to hide your details and push to github